# Can one android app mute notifications of another app?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to make an app (Service?) that counts incoming notifications from another app and then change the behavior of those notifications?

Ssay contact A sends you a number of messages via Whatsapp/Telegram/... and after X notifications you could mute the sound of more incoming notifications of A via that app but leave other notifications/sounds untouched?

Comment: I do not think that this is possible with a normal application. Otherwise, every app would be able to suppress or modify notifications of other apps. However, probably privileged apps (signed with the same signature as the OS image) would be able to do this.

Comment: @Yury The app doesn't necessarily have to suppress or modify the notification of another app, it might be enough to change notification _settings_ for that app with a specific filter. But as far as I understand, user interaction is needed for this sort of action and it can't be done programmatically. But I have never coded an Android app, so I don't know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.